# Changing variable's value using button in Tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, variables, button, tkinter

I want to change a variable when I click any of the buttons login or register so as to open proper tkinter windows to create a window which asks for login or register. When I run this code and clicked register it doesn't changes the value of the variable.What I am doing wrong?
Also if there is any better way of asking user what to do, please mention it.

```
x=3
def vall():
   global x
   x=0
def valr():
   global x
   x=1
main=Tk()
main.title("Karren")
row=Frame(main)
l=Button(main,text="Login",command=(lambda *args:vall))
l.pack(side=LEFT, padx=50, pady=50)
r=Button(main,text="Register",command=(lambda *args:valr))
r.pack(side=LEFT, padx=50, pady=50)
main.mainloop()

if x==1:
   if __name__ == '__main__':
      root = Tk()
      root.title("Register")
      ents = makeform(root, fields)
      root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))   
      b1 = Button(root,fg="orange",bg="white", text='Show', command=(lambda 
e=ents: fetch(e)))
      b1.bind("<Enter>",turnRed)
      b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
      b2 = Button(root,fg="orange",bg="white", text='Quit', 
command=root.destroy)
      b2.bind("<Enter>",turnRed)
      b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
      root.mainloop()
```

P.S.- If you want to see the full code of this gui class or the login and register class please let me know.

Comment: change `command=(lambda *args:vall)` to `command = vall`. Your commands for one do not actually call on your functions. the 2nd thing wrong is that you have an if statement that will only run on init and you need to have it called after you change your variable x. This means you probably need to move your if statement into a function of its own. A 3rd problem is you are trying to run 2 instances of Tk() and this is wrong for tkinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

The first is how your button commands are set up. You do not need to use lambda for this instance because all you are doing is calling to a function. You are not trying to pass arguments.

So you will need to change your commands from:

```
l=Button(main,text="Login",command=(lambda *args:vall))
r=Button(main,text="Register",command=(lambda *args:valr))
```

To:

```
l=Button(main,text="Login",command=vall)
r=Button(main,text="Register",command=valr)
```

The 2nd problem is related to how you have your `if` statement set up. Currently the `if` statement will only run once on the start of the program. So what you need to do is move your if statement into its own function and run that function after variable `x` has been changed.

Something like this should do:

```
def check_and_start():
    if x==1:
        main.destroy() # added to remove the other window before you start a new tkinter instance.
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            root = Tk()
            root.title("Register")
            ents = makeform(root, fields)
            root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))   
            b1 = Button(root,fg="orange",bg="white", text='Show', command=(lambda 
            e=ents: fetch(e)))
            b1.bind("<Enter>",turnRed)
            b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
            b2 = Button(root,fg="orange",bg="white", text='Quit', 
            command=root.destroy)
            b2.bind("<Enter>",turnRed)
            b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
            root.mainloop()
```

That being said you will need to change your functions `vall()` and `valr` to have a call to that function.

Should look something like this:

```
def vall():
    global x
    x=0
    check_and_start() # runs the check function needed to read the updated x variable.

def valr():
    global x
    x=1
    check_and_start()
```

All and all you code should look something like this:

```
from tkinter import *

x=3

def check_and_start():
    if x==1:
        main.destroy()
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            root = Tk()
            root.title("Register")
            ents = makeform(root, fields)
            root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))   
            b1 = Button(root,fg="orange",bg="white", text='Show', command=(lambda 
            e=ents: fetch(e)))
            b1.bind("<Enter>",turnRed)
            b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
            b2 = Button(root,fg="orange",bg="white", text='Quit', 
            command=root.destroy)
            b2.bind("<Enter>",turnRed)
            b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
            root.mainloop()

def vall():
    global x
    x=0
    check_and_start()

def valr():
    global x
    x=1
    check_and_start()

main=Tk()

main.title("Karren")
row=Frame(main)
l=Button(main,text="Login",command=vall)
l.pack(side=LEFT, padx=50, pady=50)
r=Button(main,text="Register",command=valr)
r.pack(side=LEFT, padx=50, pady=50)

main.mainloop()
```

Keep in mind that some of your stuff in the `if` statement I cannot verify (`ents = makeform(root, fields)`) because of the missing code however this example should be enough to point you in the right direction.